# What is the http.proxy in 'git config --global http.proxy https://127.0.0.1:3128'

Tags: windows, git

When I do on the cmd:

```
git config --global
```

I get a help text!

But... nowhere in the listed help text I can read about the placeholder/variable after the '`Config file location`' '`--global`'

Thus I ask you to what meaning is that '`http.proxy`'  term mapping?

What is that "http.proxy" Is it a windows system/environment variable?

Comment: Have you never tried `--help` in any command line application? See [`man git-config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for a description of the configuration keys and values.

Comment: @Zeta Have you ever read, that I recieved the help text via 'git config --global' which I wrote above?!

Comment: Sure, but that's the (short) __usage__ (description), not the __complete help message__. Compare `git config --global` and `git config`. There's a reason I added the `--help`. Learn about manuals and documentation.

Comment: And I assume there is a reason why the git devs did not wrote HELP when you do 'git config --global' because some might think that is the help manual...

Comment: Well, you've tried `git`, right? It has `git help` right in the last paragraph. Either way, whenever you want to learn more about a command, use `-h`, `--help` or `man <command>` (the last isn't available on Windows). This, by the way, is a convention on *nix. If you want to use the command line, learn how to get to know your commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the command:

```
git config --global $setting $value
```

Does just that: set `$setting` to `$value` in the global Git configuration file.

As for the particular setting `http.proxy`: this sets up a proxy server for all commands Git carries out over HTTP.

See [the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> **http.proxy**
>
> Override the HTTP proxy, normally configured using the http_proxy, https_proxy, and all_proxy environment variables (see curl(1)). In addition to the syntax understood by curl, it is possible to specify a proxy string with a user name but no password, in which case git will attempt to acquire one in the same way it does for other credentials. See gitcredentials[7] for more information. The syntax thus is [protocol://][user[:password]@]proxyhost[:port]. This can be overridden on a per-remote basis; see remote.<name>.proxy

You can learn more through typing `man git-config` or `git config --help`.

Comment: When I did 'git config --global' in the CMD as I wrote I got the help! But I could not anywhere read about the $setting. Could you point me there?

Comment: No, that doesn't show you the help, that just shows you the command's _syntax_. My answer contains a link to the online help page and two commands to obtain the help locally.

Comment: Well its listing all possible parameters and its meaning thats for me a help actually. I am just missing the '$setting" parameter

Comment: No, `$setting` is not an actual git-config parameter, it is a placeholder used as example in my answer. Again, `git config` without `--help` shows you the **syntax** of the git-config command, not all possible parameters.

Comment: Why don't you get a book about working in the command line, @HelloWorld? There's [currently a sale](https://www.humblebundle.com/books/no-starch-hacking-books), and even though its focusing the linux command line, it will help you to use git-bash, especially since your tag history indicates that you don't have much experience with the command line (yet).

Comment: Thanks, but I dont buy a book for every question ;-)